# Using or in list comprehension

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I'm trying to take out every number between 1 to 10 that is divisible by either 5 or 3

Here is my code till now -

```
giveList = 
[ x
 | x <- [1..10] ,
 (x `mod` 5 == 0) or (x `mod` 3 == 0)
]
```

And then I load the function in ghci. But it's giving me a error -

```
> [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( problem1.hs, interpreted )

problem1.hs:4:10:
    The function `x `mod` 5 == 0' is applied to two arguments,
    but its type `Bool' has none
    In the expression: (x `mod` 5 == 0) or (x `mod` 3 == 0)
    In a stmt of a list comprehension:
      (x `mod` 5 == 0) or (x `mod` 3 == 0)
    In the expression:
      [x | x <- [1 .. 10], (x `mod` 5 == 0) or (x `mod` 3 == 0)]
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

My question is -

- Can we use 'or' in list comprehensions?
- If not, please tell me how it can be done in other ways

I'm new to functional programming, please help me.

Comment: In any case, `or` wouldn't be an infix. you'd have to say `\`or\``!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `or` in list comprehensions, but

```
Prelude> :t or
or :: [Bool] -> Bool
```

that is not the one you need at that place, it's a function that checks whether any element in the list is `True`. There you need

```
(||) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
```

And if you want to use a function with a name consisting of letters infix, you need to enclose it in backticks, like you did with `mod`, but since `or` takes only one argument, you cannot apply that function infix.

A correct version of your list would be

```
giveList = [ x | x <- [1 .. 10], x `mod` 5 == 0 || x `mod` 3 == 0]
```

Comment: Thanks, functional programming seems really wierd to me. I'll accept answer as correct in about 7 mins.

Comment: @Vineet No weirder than C, which uses the exact same operators.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez, I'm talking about functional programming, not about operators.

Answer (score 8):

`or` has a type signature of `or :: [Bool] -> Bool`. It takes a *list* of Boolean values, and returns `True` if any one of them is `True`, or `False` otherwise.

The function you're looking for is `|| :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool`. It takes *two* Boolean values, and returns `True` if either of them is `True`, or `False` otherwise.

```
[x | x <- [1..10], x `mod` 5 == 0 || x `mod` 3 == 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do list comprehension like that:

```
[x | x <- [1..10], ((x `mod` 3) == 0) || ((x `mod` 5) == 0)]
```

`or` function works on lists

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I might be not so bad to use `or` here:

```
[x | x <- [1..10], or $ map ((==0).(x `mod`)) [3,5]]
```

... or probably more readable ...

```
[x | x <- [1..10], any (==0) $ map (x `mod`) [3,5]]
```

The down side is that it might look a little bit scary, but on the up side you can easily test for more divisors that way.